# Embarrassing bug in Safari

Tags: ios, ipad, safari

I have had a rather embarrassing bug for a while now. It has to do with safari on my iPad and adult websites.
After every visit to one of those websites, I always clear my browser history. However, one page just sticks in my suggested websites. I only have to type in an "X" or a "W", and it pops up in the suggested websites, like shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSQKG.png), even though I have [cleared my history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mjkz.png).

If anyone knows a solution to this somewhat embarrassing problem, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Besides your issue, won't using **Private Browsing** be a better option than clearing your cache / history every time?

Comment: It indeed seems to be a better option, and I will most definitely do this every time I want to walk the dog. However, this doesn't change the fact that my iPad has been "marked" by this "tag", and as of such I am eager to find a solution.

Comment: Indeed. I was just making sure that you were aware of this *other* option.

Comment: Does signing out of iCloud and clearing the history solve the problem?

Comment: Signing out of it on the iPad?

Answer (score 5):

Note that if you use iCloud on a Mac and your iPad (or other iOS devices) (the same account), open tabs will appear on the iPad and vice versa in the *iCloud Tabs* section (next to bookmarks on iPad). This could be where such a suggestion is coming from. I would suggest clearing history and cookies/data on all devices using iCloud (yes you will lose logged in state for many sites and will need to re-sign in).

On your iOS devices, make sure you are clearing your history *and* data using the Settings app, and not by manually deleting entries in Safari's bookmark menu. You can also disable Safari with iCloud using the Settings app under the *iCloud* section.

After you have reset everything, when you want to visit sites and not keep history, you can use Safari's privacy mode. To do this in Safari (iOS 7), when you tap the address bar, tap *Private* above the keyboard on the left side to toggle privacy mode. If you are using a physical keyboard, this option will still show at the bottom of the screen.

I use Chrome as my main browser on iOS. There you tap the button on the top right (next to the address bar most of the time) and then tap *New Incognito* Tab* to enter incognito mode.

[image: Clear history]

[image: Clear cookies and data]

Comment: I tapped both "Clear History" and "Clear Cookies and Data" in the settings, but to no avail. Therefore I conclude that the problem must lie within the iCloud issue. I will try erasing my browser history and cookies on my laptop as soon as I can access it.